# call to mktime() returns -1 with no apparent reason

Tags: c, linux, time, embedded

When can the call to mktime in C program can return -1, assuming the value passed to it are valid only.

In documentation it is mentioned as If the calendar time cannot be represented as valid, a value of -1 is returned.

Is it possible if anyone can share code behind for this mktime function call to understand what can fail it?

P.S The environment is linux on m68k processor

Comment: Suggest posting the values of `struct tm` used.

Comment: you could search the source code here if it's not this: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time.c#L322

Comment: @chux: The question asks for a description of the situations that can cause an error; it is not asking about an error the OP has observed.

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk: That does not look like an implementation of the user-visible `mktime` because it neither normalizes the `struct tm` it is passed and sets the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components nor determines whether an error as occurred. I suspect it is a routine with the same name with a subset of the function intended solely for limited use inside the kernel.

Comment: @chux we believe set valid values in struct tm_sec,tm_min,tm_hour,tm_mon,tm_year,tm_mday. We have never been able to capture these value, when it fails , because it happens very random sometimes.:(

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk Thanks for the link.yes we use this in userspace hence that kernel implementation may not be applicable.

Comment: @OP Given that `mktime()` accepts typical values as well as values just outside its range, the conclusion is that some of the values are _interesting_ or that the final `time_t` is outside the range 0 to 0x7FFFFFFF (or whatever max time is).  Although values outside the usual field range should not in itself cause an error, `tm_hour` with an extreme  value of `24*BigNum` which should cancel a `tm_mday` of `-BigNum`, might not work.

Comment: @OP, you also need to set a valid value in `tm_isdst`.  Everything but `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`.

Answer (score 3):

`mktime` may fail if the time represented by the `struct tm` it is passed is outside the range that can be represented by the `time_t` type.

Comment: It probably could also fail if the `struct tm` is meaningless like e.g. a `tm_mday` of 42 or -17 ....(or a `tm_mon` of 12 or 131)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The documentation specifies that the fields may have values outside their normal ranges and that they are normalized by `mktime`.